# How do I keep Juju in sync across multiple computers?

Tags: sync, juju

Juju is great when it's being used on a single workstation. However I have two laptops, and a Desktop that I use fairly often.

If I bootstrap an environment on my desktop, I'd like to interact with the Juju environment on my laptop(s). How do I do this?